# Spark compression when writing to external Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

I'm inserting into an external hive-parquet table from Spark 2.1 (using `df.write.insertInto(...)`. By setting e.g.

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=GZIP")
```

I can switch between SNAPPY,GZIP and uncompressed. I can verify that the file size (and filename ending) is influenced by these settings. I get a file named e.g.

> part-00000-5efbfc08-66fe-4fd1-bebb-944b34689e70.gz.parquet

However **if I work with partitioned Hive table**, this setting does not have any effect, the file size is always the same. In addition, the filename is always

> part-00000

Now how can I change (or at least verify) the compression codec of the parquet files in the partitioned case?

My table is :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(`const` string, `x` int)
PARTITIONED BY (`year` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you create external table, I would proceed like this :

First write your parquet dataset with the required compression:

```
df.write
 .partitionBy("year")
 .option("compression","<gzip|snappy|none>")
 .parquet("<parquet_file_path>")
```

you can check as before with the file extension.
Then,you can create your external table as follow :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(`const` string, `x` int)
PARTITIONED BY (`year` int)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '<parquet_file_path>';
```

If the external table already exists in Hive, you just need to run to refresh your table:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE test;
```

Comment: I was asking about inserting into an existing table

Comment: Using `SaveMode.Append` would add some new files with new data and using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` will refresh the table. But ok I don't use insertInto method