# Why would spark insertInto not write parquet files with a .parquet extension?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a tool written in Scala that uses Spark's Dataframes API to write data to HDFS. This is the line that writes the data:

```scala
temp_table.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(tableName)
```

One of our internal teams is using the tool on their hadoop/spark cluster and when it writes files to HDFS it is doing so without a .parquet extension on the files which (for reasons I won't go into) creates downstream problems for them.

Here is a screenshot provided by that team which shows those files that don't have the .parquet extension:

[image]

Note that we have verified that they ARE parquet files (i.e. they can be read using `spark.read.parquet(filename)`)

I have been unable to reproduce this problem in my test environment, when I run the same code there the files get written with a .parquet extension.

Does anyone know what might cause parquet files to not be written with a .parquet extension?

Comment: I think the "reason" is because you have a partitioned table, with non-partitioned tables, the file endings are correct, see also my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023847/spark-compression-when-writing-to-external-hive-table

Comment: Hadoop never uses file extensions at all - except to mark compressed text files with `.gz` or `.snappy` or the like. And historically Spark borrowed a lot of the Hadoop code base, especially for file formats it did not have a custom read/write interface yet. That might explain why you see different naming conventions in different contexts -- and honestly I am amazed that anyone would assume Spark used file extensions at all...

Comment: Thank you for your comment Samson however I don't appreciate the derogatory tone of your last sentence. If I'm making an assumption it is only because the behaviour I have seen up to now, and during my testing today, is that when spark writes parquet files they have an extension. I do not understand how an assumption could be construed as "amazing". Thank you again for taking the time to comment.

Comment: The explanation regarding hadoop's use (or none-use) of file extensions is certainly interesting, I shall investigate on that basis, thank you.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth thank you, after reading your question I am wondering whether the cause is the use of external tables. I shall check with my colleagues in the internal team I referred to tomorrow as to whether they are using external or managed tables.